# What abilities are affected by Radiance?

Tags: destiny

So the Radiance skill says that your abilities are boosted, but which abilities are boosted?

[image: Radiance skill]

Is it just melee? Does it include grenades? What use is this skill on it's own without any upgrades?

Comment: It does allow you to throw around grenades like candy. I don't know definitively what else it might effect and how though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radiance greatly speeds up cooldown times for your melee ability (energy drain, scorch) and grenade. You also drop at least one light orb for every enemy you kill while Radiance is active.

I believe cooldown times are the only thing boosted by the base Radiance ability. I've never noticed any damage boost per grenade or melee ability while using Radiance. It simply lets you use a lot more of them in a short time span.

[Source](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Sunsinger) for more sunsinger/radiance information.

**Edit:** ran a quick test last night: hit a dreg with a fusion grenade, then I activated Radiance and hit another dreg of the same level with another fusion grenade. The grenade did the same damage to both enemies. Similar tests with scorch produced the same result.

Comment: If you have "Song of Flame" (While active, Radiance reduces all cooldowns for nearby allies) does that apply the exact same effect to allies or is it a lesser effect. Also do you know what the range is on that? Or is this better asked as a brand new question do you reckon (it seems very related so I'm a bit unsure if it would just be better to expand this answer).

Comment: This question was more focused on the base Radiance ability (buffs applied without Song of Flame, Radiant Skin, Fireborn). You might be better off asking that as a separate question. Plus, hey, free rep.

Comment: I've asked that at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201866/radiance-and-song-of-flame if you want to go and answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

In PVP the melee attack whilst using radiance is a one hit kill rather than the usual two (hitting an enemie with full health and armour).

So I would say that the melee damage is increased but this is just from personal experience/opinion.