# Radiance and Song of Flame

Tags: destiny

Following on from a question asking about the effects of radiance I would be interested to know in the effects of Song of Flame. According to the description it reduces all cooldowns for nearby allies. Does it reduce it by the same amount as the warlocks cooldowns are reduced by or is the effect allies get reduced?

Also what is the range of "nearby"?

Comment: http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Song_of_Flame says that it's a 10 meters radius and all allies within this will get the buff. So i would say it's the same amount of reduction for everybody who get the buff. Dont ask me how much the reduction is

Comment: The link provided above states "Your fireteam can spam waves of grenades when timed correctly" in the Tips and Tricks section. To me, that sounds like teammates' grenade/melee cooldowns are reduced by about the same rate as the warlock's. I can't say for sure without testing, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a lot of research has been done by the guy who started this thread: http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2skp25/sga_song_of_flame_and_how_it_interacts_with_stats/.

That post suggests that the user sees better reductions than those nearby.

It also says the range is 8m but the effect lasts for 5 seconds after you leave that range.

Other interesting things of note are that heart of praxic fire effects not just the warlock but those near him too.

More detailed analysis can be found there including exact figures for cooldowns on various combinations (ie 0 discipline, 100% discipline, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

According to this link it's 10 meters for allies.

http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Song_of_Flame

Comment: Hi Sam. Nitro.de already suggested the info on that page in comments. I'm still looking for info on how big the effect is on allies...

Comment: Oops sorry didn't spot that!

Comment: Not a problem. Was as much as anything a reason why I am not going to make yours an accepted answer. Still useful info though so +1ing it as a half answer. :)